# Button not applying accentColor

Tags: android, xml

This is the button layout

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/retry_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.../>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#1da1f2</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1b95e0</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#003e59</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Screenshot from layout preview

[image]

Screenshot from device and emulator

[image]

Why the accentColor is not applied at background button on device?

Comment: class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the error.
I set the theme below at this specific Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".view.activity.SplashScreen"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

To fix, I created this style:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And applied:

```
<activity android:name=".view.activity.SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `Manifest`

add the theme

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    />
```

Comment: do you have  "android:theme.." in your activity inside the manifest?

Comment: @BrunoDiego try to remove this line         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"

Comment: Doing it, I would get the grey default style. :( But I found the error and the fix, I posted below. Tks